# How to search documents which has specified type and contain specific value in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, search, mongodb-query

I inserted 3 documents into mongodb like this:

```
db.collection.insert({id:1, value:[1, 2, 3]})
db.collection.insert({id:2, value:[2, 4, 5]})
db.collection.insert({id:3, value:1})
```

Then I want to:

1. get the documents whose value's type is an Array and contains 1
2. get any documents whose value contains or equal 1 or 2 or 5

Could Anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the documents whose value's type is an Array and contains 1

Use the [**`$type`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#type) operator

```js
db.collection.find({ "value": { "$type": 4 }, "value": 1})
```

> I want to get any documents whose value contains or equal 1 or 2 or 5

Use the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).Quoting the documentation

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

```js
db.collection.find({ "value": { "$in": [1,2,5] }})
```

You can do it in one query

```js
db.collection.find({ 
    "$or": [
               { "value": { "$type": 4 }, "value": 1 }, 
               { "value" : { "$in": [1,2,5]}}
           ]
})
```